# Log4j2 - Why is my "Logger" element hiding content from my "Root" logger?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

Before someone closes this question off as a duplicate, just hear me out... I have read through countless blog posts, tutorials, FAQs and SO questions for days now and I'm no closer to understanding *why* I'm getting this specific behaviour.

---

## Configuration

My `log4j2.xml` config file contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="APP_NAME">MyCoolApp</Property>
        <Property name="BASE_PACKAGE">my.cool.package</Property>
        <Property name="LOG_DIR">${env:LOG_ROOT:-logs}</Property>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">%d [%t] %-5level %c{1.}:%L:%M | %m%n</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="AppLogFile" fileName="${LOG_DIR}/${APP_NAME}.log" filePattern="${LOG_DIR}/archive/${APP_NAME}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
        </RollingFile>

        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="${BASE_PACKAGE}" level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="AppLogFile"/>
        </Logger>

        <Root level="TRACE">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Then each class initialises a logger with `private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();`.

## Runtime

From my understanding of log levels, loggers and appenders, this should give me the following:

- All `INFO` and higher level logging output to file
- All `TRACE` and higher level logging output to console

Meanwhile, if I run the app when the `AppLogFile` appender is enabled, I get less output to the console; counting from only after the Log4j initialisation, I get 255 lines compared to 367.

Looking through the console and file output, when the `AppLogFile` appender is enabled, I don't get any `TRACE` or `DEBUG` output, only `INFO` and higher. When I comment out just that appender (without changing anything else), then I get everything to console, including `TRACE` and `DEBUG`.

I've tried playing around with reordering the "console" and "file" related elements, I've tried explicitly enabling and disabling the logger's `additivity` property, I've tried using filters in the appenders and loggers, and even multiple appender references inside one logger with explicit `level` properties.

All I want is to get everything to go to the console and everything `INFO` level and higher to go to a file. What am I missing here..?

Comment: Just switch both elements in `<Loggers>` element (Root with ref console comes first than logger with ref logfile).

Comment: Just tried that again, but I get the same results as before. I edited my question to add notes on what logging output is missing, just in case that helps narrow it down..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `level` attribute and the `<AppenderRef>` element are entirely independent:

- Specifying `level` *changes* the logging level of the given logger and all sub-loggers.
- Specifying `<AppenderRef>` *adds*<sup>1</sup> another appender to the given logger and all sub-loggers.

The fact that you do both at the same time, doesn't affect those independent effects.

If you want to limit log entries for the Appender, specify the `level` attribute on the `<AppenderRef>` instead.

<sup>1) If you wanted the Appender to *replace*, you need to specify `additivity="false"`</sup>

---

> (OP edit) Just for the sake of clarity, between what I learned from this answer and the [Log4j2 FAQ](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/faq.html#config_sep_appender_level); I streamlined things a bit and ended up with the following `<Loggers>` configuration:

```
<Loggers>
    <Root level="TRACE">
        <AppenderRef ref="AppLogFile" level="INFO"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

Comment: After seeing your answer, I did try moving the `level` property around between those elements.. I still couldn't get it quite right, but it was definitely making a difference. -- Work is done for the day and I'm home now, but I'll fire up my PC just now and see what else I can do. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Thank you so very much; I just went through my configuration again now and managed to get it working exactly as I need. Looks like there's still a great deal for me to learn about Log4j2, but at least now I've got a good base configuration file to work from. :D